# change style of widgets (editTextPreference, listPreference, dialogPreference) in android

Tags: android, android-theme

I created an application where I applied theme Theme.Holo.Light. Now I want to change look of my edittexts and dialogs in PreferenceActivity to look like in Theme.Dark. How can I apply different Theme to this particular Widgets?